# Is it possible to get 'automatic' updating (binding) from Firestore to a React/Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm wondering whether it's possible to have changes in a Firestore DB automatically reflected in a React app.  That is -- if I have the correct terminology -- whether I can bind the two together, with the Firestore DB acting as a model and the React app acting as the view.

Failing using something like WebSockets, I can't think of a way that doesn't involve some sort of polling.

I did come across `react-redux-firebase`, which allows to [connect Firestore to Redux](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore).  But on a first glance, I can't tell whether this means that changes in Firestore are automatically transmitted to Redux, that is whether `react-redux-firebase` does some sort of polling, etc, on its own.  Or whether you have to query the Firestore data yourself.

(Full disclosure: reflecting changes in React from a Firestore DB is a small part of a coding challenge I'm working on, but I figure it's fair game to ask on Stack Overflow to see if I'm heading down a viable path, since this is what I'd do in 'real life' in any case.  I suspect I'll need to do the polling myself, but wanted to see if there were any library, like `react-redux-firebase`, that would 'push' the data from Firestore to React/Redux automatically).

Comment: Sure is: use a listener as shown here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen, and then in `onSnapshot` set the data to the state of your react component, which then triggers a rerender of the UI with the updated content. If you have problems making this work, edit your question to show what you've done.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen -- One question, I have a config object which contains private key info, etc.  In a Node app, I can access the firestore account using firebase-admin, `    firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({ credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(configObject)});`, but when I try to use the Firebase Javascript SDK (can't use firebase-admin in React) I don't see any similar method.  That is, using the SDK, or react-redux-firebase, they all seem to want a different object, using the API key, leaving auth for later.  How to login automatically, using the credentials that have the private key?

Comment: You can't securely use the Admin SDK in client-side code. It is starting to sound like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at this point.

Comment: Fair enough, I think this is a rabbit hole. Thanks for your help though. I think the problem is that was a full-stack test, not a Firebase test, and I'm getting lost in implementation details of Firebase, when I don't have sufficient privileges to follow any of the routes suggested by the documentation.  I've implemented a polling solution where the React front polls an express backend that CAN log into the Firebase DB through the admin -- that's the best I can do for now...

Comment: Did the initial comment posted by Frank van Puffelen answered your question?

Comment: I believe so, but could not test it since I did not have the necessary access to the Firebase account.